# Getting started with Gazebo for ROS?

Tags: gazebo, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello fellow ROS users,
I just started on a project using the ROS navigation stack. I am using Ubuntu Trusty and ROS Indigo. I already have a ROS project that I have worked on and I am able to simulate the same using Rviz. Now, I would like to use Gazebo for the simulation?

Anybody with pointers on how to get started? Is there a way to directly connect my ROS project to Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245631/getting-started-with-gazebo-for-ros?/) by [adityakamath](https://answers.ros.org/users/28154/adityakamath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2016-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is where I would start, [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=connect_ros).

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1